=Sum(COUNTIF array returns 2 extra number?
I am tracking lottery numbers (pick5) with 10 rows, using the formula
=SUM(COUNTIF(K5:F5,K$16:F$16))
The picks are on row 5 and the winning numbers are on row 16.  As long as there are 5 numbers the formula works fine.  I made sure that I hit CTR+SHIFT+ENTER to enter it as an array formula.
BUT, when I extend the formula 1 extra column to add the POWER BALL number, the total adds 2 more in the formula instead of 1 extra if the numbers in the SUM match.  It started doing this when I used autofill for each of the 10 lines of picks.
Example:    picks are 1,2,3,4,5   The winning numbers are 1,2,3,4,5
I will see a result 5 numbers as the sum of the count equals 5.
Example:  Adding the extra column for the 6th number result in the following;
Picks 1,2,3,4,5,6    The winning numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,6
I will see a result 6 numbers as the sum of the count equals 7
I do not know why the count is incremented by 1.
I have manually retyped the formula to no avail.  I have opened a new tab and started from scratch ONLY pasting the values and NOT the formulas and it does the same thing.
I can work around it, but it is bugging me.
Thanks

You forgot to share what data is in row 16 column K to F

Could you please share us some screenshots of your data and the formula in formula bar?

What version of excel are you using? CTR+SHIFT+ENTER may not be required for newer versions. I ask this as the formula looks correct and I am not able to replicate the error you are describing. FWIW an alternative formula giving you a TRUE/FALSE response is =AND(F5:K5=$F$16:$K$16)
